How to use a @Bean with void return type defined in a 3rd party library in SpringBoot 3.x app
My SpringBoot 3.X app is using a 3rd party library (dependency) which has a @Bean defined as follows in a @Configuration class:
@Bean
public void performUpdateForAllInstances() throws Exception {....}

I am using @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "package.path.from.third.party.*") to scan the configuration.
On starting the app I get the below error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Bean method 'performUpdateForAllInstances' must not be declared as void; change the method's return type or its annotation.

The same dependency works fine in a old app which uses SpringBoot 2.X
I cannot make changes inside the 3rd party app, please can you guide me on how to overcome this.

You don't as that doesn't make sense and as such is now forbidden in newer Spring versions.

Ok. is there any way to handle this apart from changing code in 3rd party app

You might be able to override the bean definition and in that overriding call the original method and return new Object(); as the bean.

There is no other way as using @Bean on void methods doesn't make sense (what is a void bean? ). This is abusing the @Bean to do some initializing callback, for which you should use other means. What you need to change is already included in the message, so tell your 3rd party provider to fix their code or don't use their configuration but copy it and fix it yourself.

@Bean on methods returning void is not supported. If you cannot change the third party code, then you can exclude the Configuration class and define the beans on your own.
Instead of including third party bean classes by scanBasePackages, use @ComponentScan, and exclude the Config class
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {basePackages = { "package.path.from.third.party" }, 
   @ComponentScan.Filter(
          type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {ThirdPartyConfig.class})})

